# Black line over the code in Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, line

I first got this problem in IntelliJ IDEA while writing code but now I"m having this in Android Studio also. 
I get a black line over my code when I place the cursor in between the code.
Is there anyone who is having the same problem as me?
I'll appreciate your help.

[image: Black line over the code in IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio]

Comment: click on insert button on your keyboard

Comment: By clicking insert Button we can show only cursor black and hide that @BishoyAbd

Comment: Please check "Selection background" color in "Settings | Editor | Color&Fonts | General - Editor"

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File`->`Settings`

Under IDE Settings expand `Editor` -> `Colors & Fonts` ->`General`

In the list shown on right scroll to `Line Number`, Now change `foreground` and `background` colors.

Comment: Not worked! 
Is it a inbuilt problem or I'm just a special case? Because I've the same problem in IntelliJ IDEA when I run Java Code. I then close the application and then open it again, but I can't do it again and again in Android because Android takes a lot of time opening! Can you please share screenshot. How to solve this?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: P.S: Recently I've found that this isn't only the case with codes, it also happens to every text that I click on!
Please see the attached screenshot at this URL:https://ibb.co/jmSuym

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem. If your using Android Studio 3.0.1 update it to the latest version or click insert on the keyboard.

After updating to the latest version of Android Studio. Do not import your settings from your previous version

Or reset Android Studio's settings by deleting the .AndroidStudio3.0 file under C:\Users[username] in Windows

For Mac remove this files
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio3.0 
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio3.0
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio3.0
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.0

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem in Android Studio, it seems to have come down as part of a buggy IDE update. Studio would work fine for about five minutes and then randomly start obscuring the current code line with a black highlight.

Anyway, clearing out all the AndroidStudio folders in C:\Users[Username] seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Android Studio 3.1.3 to solve this issue. File > Invalidates caches and restart.

Comment: I've started having the same problem again even after restarting it, sometimes it works but as you know restarting Android Studio, again and again, is very time-consuming.

Comment: I understand. This is an issue of Android Studio 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Press insert key.
if you can not find,insert key near delete key.